# COUNT number of rows on table with LEFT JOIN returns 1 when not exists

Tags: php, sql, left-join

I've two tables, for example:

**post**:

```
id | author | content | date
1  | Lucas  | Hello!  | 2016
2  | Igor   | Hi!     | 2016
```

**comment**:

```
id | post_id | content | date
1  | 2       | hehehe  | 2016
2  | 1       | hahaha  | 2016
3  | 2       | huhuhu  | 2016
```

And I to do a `SELECT` that return all posts and a `COUNT` of rows of all comments with `post.id = comment.id`.

So, I tried:

```
SELECT p.id, p.author, p.content, p.date, COUNT(*) AS numComments FROM post p LEFT JOIN comment ON p.id = post_id WHERE p.author = '$author' GROUP BY p.id DESC LIMIT 12
```

And I got do it. But, even when no exists comments with `p.id = post_id` he returns 1.

So, I tried:

```
SELECT p.id, p.author, p.content, p.date, CASE WHEN COUNT(*) < 1 THEN '0' ELSE COUNT(*) END AS numComments FROM post p LEFT JOIN comment ON p.id = post_id WHERE p.author = '$author' GROUP BY p.id DESC LIMIT 12
```

But the result is the same. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outer joins return a row even if there's no matching data you need to count a column from the **inner** table, usually it's the column used in join:

```
SELECT p.id, p.author, p.content, p.date, COUNT(post_id) AS numComments
FROM post p LEFT JOIN comment ON p.id = post_id 
WHERE p.author = '$author' 
GROUP BY p.id -- seems to be mysql, otherwise you need to add more columns to the list
```

If you don't want to show rows with a zero count simply switch to an 
INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

you can get count by this way, also last is order by not group by:

```
SELECT p.id, p.author, p.content, p.date, 
(select COUNT(*) from comment where p.id = comment.post_id) AS numComments FROM post p 
WHERE p.author = '$author' 
ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 12
```